# Deep copy of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, copy, clone

I wanted to get an object on production and do an exact replica( copy over its contents)  to another object of same type. I tried doing this in 3 ways from ruby console which none of them worked:

1. Let's say you have the `tt` as the first object you want to copy over and `tt2` as the replica  object. The first approach I tried is cloning the array

   ```
   tt2.patients  = tt.urls.patients
   tt2.doctors   = tt.segments.doctors
   tt2.hospitals = tt.pixels.hospitals
   ```
2. Second approach I tried is duplicating the array which is actually the same as cloning the array:

   ```
   tt2.patients  = tt.patients.dup
   tt2.doctors   = tt.doctors.dup
   tt2.hospitals = tt.hospitals.dup
   ```
3. Third approach I tried is marhsalling.

   ```
   tt2.patients  = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(tt.patients)) 
   tt2.doctors   = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(tt.doctors)) 
   tt2.hospitals = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(tt.hospitals))
   ```

None of the above works for deep copying from one array to another. After trying out each approach individually above, all the contents of the first object (`tt`) are nullified (patients, doctors and hospitals are gone). Do you have any other ideas on copying the contents of one object to another? Thanks.

Comment: You're merely setting your variables in the first example. Try tt2.patients = tt.patiens.clone instead.

Answer (score 19):

Easy!

```
@new_tt            = tt2.clone
@new_tt.patients   = tt2.patients.dup
@new_tt.doctors    = tt2.doctors.dup
@new_tt.hospitals  = tt2.hospitals.dup
@new_tt.save
```

Comment: This works great. new_tt has all the info I need now. However, all the contents of tt2(patients, doctors,hospitals) are gone after doing what you have told me above. How do you keep the contents of tt2?

Comment: Woops! I had a syntactical mistake there. I updated the code above. Try it out.

Comment: What is different between this and what his second approach?

Answer (score 6):

This is what [ActiveRecord::Base#clone](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/clone) method is for:

> @bar = @foo.clone
>
> @bar.save

Answer (score 2):

[Ruby Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/) is a set of useful extensions to Ruby and has a [deep_clone](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Kernel:deep_clone) method that might work for you.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore. New link to [deep_clone is here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Kernel:deep_clone).