# Both dup and clone return different objects, but modifying them alters the original object

Tags: ruby, object, duplicates, clone

I have an array of values that I use as a reference for order when I'm printing out hash values.  I'd like to modify the array so that the array values are "prettier".  I figured I'd just dup or clone the array, change the values and the original object would remain unchanaged.  However (in irb)...

```
@arr = ['stuff', 'things']
a = @arr.clone
b = @arr.dup
```

So, at the very least, a and @arr are different objects:

```
a.object_id == @arr.object_id
=> false
```

But now it gets strange

```
a[0].capitalize!
a
=> ['Stuff', 'things']
@arr
=> ['Stuff', 'things'] ##<-what?
b
=> ['Stuff', 'things']## <-what???
```

ok... so modifying one changes the others, lets change it back?

```
a[0] = 'stuff'
a
=> ['stuff', 'things']
@arr
=> ['Stuff', 'things'] ## <- WHAT?????
```

For completeness b[1].capitalize! has the same effect, capitalizing all three array's second position

So... does the bang on the end of capitalize make it extra potent?  Enough to cross over to other objects?? I know of other ways of doing this, but this just seemed extremely odd to me.  I assume this has something to do with being a "shallow copy". Suggestions on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dup`and `clone` make new instances of the arrays, but not of the content, it is no deep copy.

See:

```
array0 = ['stuff', 'things']
array1 = array0.clone
array2 = array0.dup

puts "Array-Ids"
p array0.object_id
p array1.object_id
p array2.object_id

puts "Object ids"
array0.each_with_index{|_,i|
  p array0[i].object_id
  p array1[i].object_id
  p array2[i].object_id
  p '--------'
}
```

The elements inside the array share the same object_id - they are the same object. The arrays have different object ids.

When you `a[0].capitalize!` you modify an object, which is part in three different arrays.

See also

- [Duplicating a Ruby array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579879/duplicating-an-array-of-strings)
- [Deep copy of arrays in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607852/deep-copy-of-arrays-in-ruby)
- [How to create a deep copy of an object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206523/how-to-create-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-ruby)

Comment: Ah... I see.  I also see that knowing what I needed was a "deep copy" would have helped my search tremendously :-P  Thanks!