# An array shared despite cloning

Tags: ruby, arrays, clone

I have a class like this:

```
class Tiles
  attr_accessor :board
  def initialize
    @board = Array.new(4) { Array.new(4) { 0 } }
  end
  ...
```

Later, I call this method:

```
def display_board
  padded_board = @board.clone
  padded_board.each_with_index do |row, x|
    row.each_with_index do |item, y|
      padded_board[x][y] = pad_number(item)
    end
    puts row.join ' '
  end
end
```

Anytime I change `padded_board`, `@board` gets changed as well. I can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: .dup performs the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because when you `clone`, you are creating a new instance of an array `@board`, but its elements, which are also arrays, are not being replaced with new instances. You are not going deeply enough to clone the end elements. You need to do deep clone. You might want to look at some answers and gems suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206523/how-to-create-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-ruby) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607852/deep-copy-of-arrays-in-ruby).

Comment: Thanks, for anyone having the same problem, this was my solution:   
   `padded_board = board.map{ |row| row.clone }`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that array is in fact a set of pointers to other objects, in your case those objects are another arrays. When you are cloning array, you are creating new pointers, which points to the same objects. By calling `padded_board[x][y]=` you are modifying the `padded_board[x]` array, which is referenced by both `@board` and `padded_board`.

To fix it, you need to duplicate not only the array, but also each element of this array. Int his case this should be sufficient:

```
   padded_board = @board.map(&:clone)
```

In more general case it is useful to extend Array with `deep_dup` method. Rails have this method defined within ActiveSupport module, whcih can also be used in any non-rails project by adding `require 'active_support/core_ext/object/deep_dup'.